# Chat Room Name revisited

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

As we have done some changes to the nature of the site, I think we should revisit the name of the chat. „The Waiting Room“ is a creative name, but it does add up to the misconception of this being a site about patient’s health problems.

Can we find other creative and fun names, that hint more at our actual scope?

Answer (score 5):

In keeping with the new direction - Grand Rounds.

> [Wikipedia: Grand rounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_rounds)
>   Grand rounds are methodology of medical education and inpatient care, consisting of presenting the medical problems and treatment of a particular patient to an audience consisting of doctors, residents, and medical students. It was first conceived by clinicians as a way for junior colleagues to round on patients.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I forget it's not common terminology.

Comment: "Grand Rounds" is a specific term, so there's no plural version.  Love it, I was going to suggest it too!

Comment: The name has been changed to Grand Rounds!

Comment: @JuanM Wow, that was quick :)

Answer (score 0):

The new direction and a pun working within SE communities?

I suggest:

"The ICU."

[Wikipedia: Intensive care unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_care_unit)

It is not entirely free of the patients seeking diagnosis connotation, but indicates a different level.